# Remember text in input via jQuery Cookie

Tags: javascript, jquery, cookies

I'm using jQuery Cookie plugin. And I want, when I write text a input, remember this text next sessions.

```
  $(".webform-submit").click(function () {
    $.cookie('telCookie', $telephoneCookie.val(), {
      expires: 365
    });
  });

  //set the value of the cookie to the element element_1
  var $telephoneCookie = $("#edit-submitted-telefon").val($.cookie("telCookie"))
```

HTML:

```
<input type="text" id="edit-submitted-telefon" name="submitted[telefon]" step="any" class="form-text form-number required">
```

But value has not my text, so this input get `undefined`

How can I fix it? Thanks.

Comment: When you're passing `$telephoneCookie.val()` to the value of the cookie are you sure that it's not null?

Comment: Yes, because my texts not writing on input value. I think, first generate input value dynamically, right?

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to make a change as you are mixing jquery variable with javascript variables

change

```js
var $.telephoneCookie = $("#edit-submitted-telefon").val($.cookie("telCookie"))
```

and also change

```js
$.cookie('telCookie', $.telephoneCookie, {
  expires: 365
});
```